# Flash (AS2) - Catch the Flash movie close event

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I want to catch the close event of the flash movie.

What would I do to do something when the flash window is closed?

Comment: More information, please. Is the action you want to do a server-side action? Or do you want to do something within flash as it's closed (such as save a sharedobject value)...

Answer (score 0):

You could poll from the window and detect a timeout server side?